# What is a def ... else ... end construct?

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
def with_else
  puts 'we enter something funny'
  if true
    puts "yes"
    'return YES'
  end
  'return what?'
else
  puts 'no'
  'return else -> no'
end

puts with_else
```

and the output is this:

```
we enter something funny
yes
no
return else -> no
```

Why don't I get an error for that? What does `def`/`else`/`end` mean?

http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/8df07

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually part of a larger syntactical structure:

```
def foo
  # method stuff
rescue
  # stuff if an exception is caught
else
  # stuff if no exception is caught
ensure
  # always run after rescue and else
end
```

But each section is optional! So you can leave out the `rescue` and `ensure` to get your example.

Comment: There should still be a warning message: warning: else without rescue is useless

Comment: There is a warning, but Ruby Fiddle (which is what OP is using) does not display it.

Comment: there is a warning, but I did not look there, because I was searching _my_ fault, in a "foreign" framework