# How to intercept ruby on Rails (framework) warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

According to this problem: [`def .. else .. end in ruby`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393153/what-is-a-def-else-end-construct), I was missing a RoR warning, because I just did not look there (in the output)

I now want to prevent my self stepping into similar 'pitfalls' in that way, that I show this warning(s) on my HTML-page (development), there it hits my eye for sure.

So is there a way to intercept this warnings, for example putting (or getting) it from @env or alike?

I actually even dont know what (or'who') the source or better the transport layer of such warnings is (Rails?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short words: no it is not - not realy

because:

1st) The `warning` is not thrown some how, it 'happens' here :   `result = Kernel.load path` in `ActiveSupport::Dependencies` : `load_file` its processed by ruby command itself

2nd) The `warning` only apears, if you change the Source with the Warning (rails things ...)

3rd) all depends of the programming environment you are using

*BUT*: you can read the (tail of the) log file of your environment (rubymine or what ever you are using), eg. with a small rails extention, and put a warning then. This is not precise, but probably better than nothing